# Error in Calling LWC inside Omniscript

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio, omniscript

Getting below error in calling LWC inside the Omniscript.

[image]

below in my LWC

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'omnistudio/omniscriptBaseMixin';
import pubsub from 'omnistudio/pubsub';

export default class LwcForCraCalculation extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track jsonData;
    renderedCallback(){

        //register the pubsub event
        pubsub.register('omniscript_step', {
            data: this.handleOmniStepLoadData.bind(this),
        });
    }
    
    handleOmniStepLoadData(data) {
        // perform logic to handle the pubsub data from the Step

        //console.log('pubsub data -- '+ JSON.stringify(data)  ); 
        this.jsonData = data.omniJsonData ;         
        console.log('jsonData -- '+ JSON.stringify(this.jsonData)  ); 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: is there any workaround ?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Lightning Web Security for LWC under session settings? According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389755&type=1) article it might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add runtimeNamespace tag in your meta.xml.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <runtimeNamespace>omnistudio</runtimeNamespace>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```